# How do I remove dependency on mfc80.dll and msvcr80.dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

My code does not use MFC.  However, when I built my static lib the party that is trying to use it is stating that they are having a hard time because my code lib has the following dependencies in it:

mfc80.dll and msvcr80.dll

Is there a way to remove those and rebuild?  I am using vs2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static library by default links to the dynamic runtime, which is why your code has a dependency on msvcr80.dll. Visual C++ programs must link to a runtime. You can change your static library to use a static runtime to remove the dependency. This is done in the Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library setting. However, the chosen runtime library must match what is used in the project that links your static library.

Your code probably depends on mfc80.dll because you have Configuration Properties | General | Use of MFC set to one of the MFC options.

In my opinion, Visual C++ (and Windows in general) was made for dynamic libraries and dynamic runtimes. Static libraries seem like more of a hack, in that they have a surprising number of limitations, pitfalls and idiosyncratic behavior. Better become familiar with producing and consuming dynamic libraries -- it's better in the long run.

Comment: Of course there is one major benefit to linking to static libraries: If your code works--and that is an important assumption--it will always work. It will not fail on user B's computer because they have some other version of the library installed.

Comment: right. that was the main thing i wanted to avoid. but using dll's is a valid suggestion as well. but since i am a novice and have never done that i think once i have this all working i will eventually make a dll friendly version as well just because.

Answer (score 0):

mscvr80.dll is the release CRT. You can remove this dependency by setting the compiler to statically link. Most likely, you're trying to load MFC because the project is set to use MFC, even though you're not using it. You can remove this in the project settings.

Although, gotta question why VS2008 would produce mfc80.dll and mscvr80.dll dependencies, instead of mfc90.dll and mscvr90.dll.

Comment: i am using vs2008 i am uncertain why that is either. how do i go about finding that out any clues? i am using a third party lib that possibly might be using mfc i have no way of knowing. so even though i have statically built the lib i either unknowingly put the mfc dependency in there or its a part of the third party lib i am using and it is naturally adding that dependency. i am not sure which atm.